# How to create SPOT VM's in my secondary_worker_config in airflow DAG for using google cloud dataproc operators?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

In UI, you can select Preemptibility as Spot in the Secondary worker nodes to create something similar:

[image]

Following is my JSON:

```
    "secondary_worker_config": {
        "num_instances": 5,
        "machine_type_uri": SOME_MACHINE_TYPE,
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
        "image_uri" : SOME_IMAGE_URI
    }
```

What is the key-value pair for a SPOT VM?

I tried to look into the following documents but did not find anything:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-use-spot#gcloud

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```json
"secondaryWorkerConfig": {
      "numInstances": 5,
      "preemptibility": "SPOT" // the default is standard preemptible, and you can provide "NON_PREEMPTIBLE" to create non-preemptible secondry workers
    }
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/secondary-vms#rest-api) is the doc.